# Windows Server 2008 R2 - How do I change IIS Settings?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ssrs-2008

I think I've looked through all the menus and control panel and I can't find anything to configure IIS.

I feel like IIS is already installed because SQL Server Reporting services has a webpage running and a virtual directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Server Manager -> Roles and verify if you have Web Server (IIS) installed. If yes, make sure you have IIS Management Console installed.

Comment: I do see the role.  Where would I check for the IIS management console?

Comment: In the "Role Features"

Comment: No, I don't have the IIS management console.  How would I add that?

Comment: check this out.. http://dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Configure-Client-Certificate-Mapping-in-FTP-75-Part-1.aspx, the image shows IIS Role Services

Comment: Open Server Manager -> Roles 
Scroll down to Web Server (IIS)
click on Add Role Services
under Management Tools -> IIS Management Console

Comment: Start -> Programs -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager — this is where you will find it.  Server Manager -> Roles takes forever to execute for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

type IIS in the search bar it should bring you to the internet services manager, or you can click start, programs, admnistrative tools and the IIS maanger should be listed

Answer (score 1):

SSRS 2008 does not require IIS to be installed, therefore the SSRS Virtual Directories will not show up in IIS configuration tools anyway!

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bwelcker/everybody-why-leave-iis)

Answer (score 1):

Use **ServerManagerCmd** to change Windows 2008 Roles.
Examples:

```
ServerManagerCmd.exe -query

ServerManagerCmd.exe -install Web-Server -resultPath installResult.xml

ServerManagerCmd.exe -inputPath install.xml -whatIf
```